# php ftp functions is not working on my production server

Tags: php, ftp

I'm using MAMP Pro on my Mac for my development environment. Here I'm using the Touki\FTP package from Packagist to handle a FTP connection.

I works great locally, but when I try it on my production environment, which is an AWS EC2 server with Ubuntu, which has Apache2 and php5 installed, but it doesn't work.

When I use `phpinfo()` I can see that the FTP extension is enabled.

Here is my code:

```
use Touki\FTP\Connection\Connection;
use Touki\FTP\FTPWrapper;

$connection = new Connection('host', 'user', 'pass');
$connection->open();

$wrapper = new FTPWrapper($connection);
$files = $wrapper->nlist("/myfolder");

foreach($files as $fileKey => $fileName) {
  $fileext = explode(".", $fileName);
  $ext = $fileext[sizeof($fileext)-1];

  if($ext == 'txt') {
    echo $fileName;
  }
}

$connection->close();
```

Comment: How do you think people will be able to help you without code?

Comment: Are you sure you have a `/myfolder` on the new server?Do you get any errors?

Comment: Yes I have /myfolder on the server. It works great locally. But when it goes to the production server it doesn't.

Comment: Check the folder rights

Comment: /myfolder is a folder on the ftp server, which the ftp-user, that i'm using has full read/write access to when connecting by any ftp client. And when using this php-script on my local development environment, it lists all the files on the ftp, but not on the production environment.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It should have been in passive mode from the production environment. So I changed the $connection to:

```
$connection = new Connection('host', 'user', 'pass', $port = 21, $timeout = 90, $passive = true);
$connection->open();
```

Now it works perfectly.